# Add Hyperlink as Label to UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I have `UserForm` and want to add a `Label` as a `HyperLink`. 
If the user clicks on the label the link `www.stackoverflow.com` should be opened.

The web-address is stored in `Cell A1` in `Sheet1`.

```
Sub UserForm_Activate()
Label1.Caption = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

So far I used the `VBA` above. It displays the link from the cell as Label. 
However, I cannot click it and use it as Hyperlink.

How do I need to modify it to make it work?

Is it also possible to give the `Label` a separate description instead of the web-address (similar to what the HYERPLINK formula in Excel does)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try either the `Click` or `DblClick` event, set the caption to your "separate description" then put the below code in your userform

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Or

```
Private Sub Label1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```